# How Go streaming read from request a.body to a newrequest‘s body

Tags: http, go

Now, i do something like this with Golang:

```
//read all bytes from body
bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
//set the bytes as NewReader to new request.body
request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, url, bytes.NewReader(bytes))
```

but i want to streaming read from original body(io.Reader) to the new, instead of read all bytes to memory by ReadAll，and then copy to NewRequest.

How can i implement this?

thx.

Comment: Have you tried just passing the body to the new request?

Comment: Yes, but cannot work well.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That is how you would "stream" the response to a new request.

Comment: for example, i read 25 bytes to buf from original body every time, and the new request can read the buf streaming instead of must wait the end of 'ReadAll' from body

Comment: What `buf` are you talking about if you pass the Body directly to the new request? Please create an [mcve] demonstrating the problem you're having.

Comment: Are sure can pass body directly to the new request？i try this but failed. Thx.

Comment: Again, what did you do _exactly_, and how did it fail? Was there a compilation error? What was the result you expected and what was the result you received?

Comment: Sorry，I made a stupid mistake. As you said， pass the Body directly is OK，thank u very much。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [`io`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/) package if you want specialized reader - writer handling, the Pipe or Tee structs might be useful.

In this case, though,

`request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, url, request.Body)`

should actually just work fine.